# Persistir informações usando ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Eu tenho a minha tela de *login* é quero mostra o nome é id do usuário logado em outra tela, para que eu possa utilizar estas informações.

No meu *controller*:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TB_USUARIO model)
    {

            //aqui vai pesquisar o login é senha
            try
            {
                var tbuscar = new UsuarioAplicacao();
                var retorno = tbuscar.ListarPorLoginSenha(model.login, model.senha);

                if (retorno != null)
                {

                    ViewBag.Login = retorno.login;
                    ViewBag.senha = retorno.senha;
                    ViewBag.nome = retorno.nomeusuario;
                    ViewBag.id = retorno.idusuario;
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "MenuPrincipal");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Erro"] = "Usuário não localizado.";
                }

                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["Erro"] = ex.Message;
            }

            return View();
        }


}
```

Quero mostra estas informações :

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@section menu{
    <!-- NAVBAR
    ================================================== -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">opciones de menú</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/Home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>


  <!-- NAVBAR FIM
  ================================================== -->

}


    <br/>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Controle: @TempData["id"]</div>
        <div class="panel-heading">Nome: @TempData["nome"] </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: E qual é a dúvida?

Comment: <div class="panel-heading">Controle:@ViewBag.nome</div> está vazio

Comment: @bigown, eu não sabia que podia votar, mais agradeço o lembrete!

Comment: Você pode votar em tudo que achar legal no site. E tem muita coisa legal pra votar :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já que vai fazer um redirecionamento, tem que usar o `TempData` mesmo. O `ViewBag` não sobrevive neste cenário.

```
TempData["Login"] = retorno.login;
TempData["senha"] = retorno.senha;
TempData["nome"] = retorno.nomeusuario;
TempData["id"] = retorno.idusuario;
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7993263/221800).

Se deseja manter a informação por toda a sessão use `Session`:

```
Session["Login"] = retorno.login;
Session["senha"] = retorno.senha;
Session["nome"] = retorno.nomeusuario;
Session["id"] = retorno.idusuario;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/TemDataSession.cs).

Comment: a sua resposta foi perfeita! agradeço!

Answer (score 3):

Eu estava pesquisando sobre *ViewBags* e acabei encontrando essa pergunta, mas a minha pergunta era:

**Utilizar *Viewbags* ou *ViewModels*?**

A resposta do @Maniero soluciona seu problema com o conceito básico da diferença entre `Viewbag`, `Viewdata` e `Tempdata`.

No entanto, eu respondo sua pergunta de forma diferente:

> Persistir informações usando *ViewBag*?

**Não!** Ou pelo menos, não dessa forma do seu exemplo.

Nesse caso, o ideal é utilizar *ViewModels*. Dê uma olhada nas duas respostas desse *post [ViewModels or ViewBags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779294/viewmodels-or-viewbag)*.

Dessa forma você criaria uma classe encapsulada do seu Login e em sua *view* você receberia uma modelo e utilizaria os dados *strongly typed*.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

LoginViewModel.cs

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Login")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo 'login' é obrigatório.")]
    public string login { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Senha")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo 'senha' é obrigatório.")]
    public string senha { get; set; }
}
```

LoginController

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        LoginViewModel login = new LoginViewModel();

        return View(login);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "login,senha")] LoginViewModel login)
    {
        LoginViewModel login = new LoginViewModel();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TbLogin.Add(login);
            db.SaveChanges();                
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

*Lembre-se: Nunca faça

```
return View();
```

em um método Post ou você vai correr um grande risco de reenvio de formulários.

Login.cshtml

```
 @model LoginViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Entrar";
        Layout = null;
    }

    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.login)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.login)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.senha)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.senha)
        </dd>    
    </dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Controller C#:

`ViewBag.Nome = "Jr";`

Html:

```html
@ViewBag.Nome
```

Comment: <div class="panel-heading">Controle:@ViewBag.nome</div> está vazio