# Sessão ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, session

Pessoal tenho um *controller* onde seto duas chaves de sessão e que capturar essas key em qualquer lugar da aplicação. (outro *controller*, ou uma *view*).

O controller está assim:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult TimetableSelect(int currentTimetableId, string currentTimetableName)
 {
     Session["TTBId"] = currentTimetableId;
     Session["TTBName"] = currentTimetableName;
     return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
 }
```

Porém na view eu consulto igual está abaixo, e sempre está retornando nulo.

```
@if (Session["TTBId"] != null && Session["TTBName"] != null)
{
  ....
}
```

Alguém pode dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Persistir informações usando ViewBag?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105806/persistir-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-usando-viewbag)

Comment: Acredito não ser duplicata, talvez pela forma de persistir a informação por uma session sim, mas, o problema inicial dele não é igual a essa do link. O problema dele é o trafego da informação pelo sistema, ocasionando erros na verificação do código. Problema maior é a falta de interação do usuário da pergunta

Answer (score 3):

`RedirectToAction` abre uma nova requisição e, portanto, evapora os dados da `Session`. Eu diria que essa não é a melhor forma de fazer o que você quer.

Prefira usar no lugar [`TempData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata(v=vs.118).aspx), que tem um tempo de vida maior:

```
[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult TimetableSelect(int currentTimetableId, string currentTimetableName)
 {
     TempData["TTBId"] = currentTimetableId;
     TempData["TTBName"] = currentTimetableName;
     return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
 }
```

*View*:

```
@if (TempData["TTBId"] != null && TempData["TTBName"] != null)
{
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o seu código esteja correto, mas, seu modo de utilização errado.

Se por acaso a aplicação passar por esse método na `variavel` `currentTimetableName` não trouxer dados ela fica sem valor (`null`) e na hora da View conferir não passa dentro daquele ***if*** (`@if (TempData["TTBId"] != null && TempData["TTBName"] != null)`), porque `TempData["TTBName"]` vai ser `null`.

***Então:***

Coloque um breakpoint tanto no `Controller` quanto na sua `View` para conferir os dados se estão sendo enviados, e também coloque na sua pergunta o fluxo de trabalho para a gravação dessas duas variáveis de **Sessão** (*Session*)

Não há problemas na utilização de `RedirectToAction` com `Session` ele não interfere e nem apaga os valores se forem passados corretamente!